# What to do if DbSet<T> MyProperty in entity framework is null

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, dbcontext

I am pretty new with entity framework, i have db first approach and i am setting the values of my model into the DbSet MyClassName. But when i am running it is giving exception that "myContext.MyClassName is null Additional information: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", i tried many solution but unable to create object of my DbSet.

```
**1st Tried**

MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.Id = stud.Id;
myObj.StudId = stud.StudId;
myObj.CourseId = stud.CourseId;

myContext.MyClass.Add(myObj) //Here exception starts with messages.


**2nd Tried**
MyClass langTest = new MyClass();
langTest.Id = 1;
langTest.StudentId = 500;
foreach(MyClass entity in myContext.MyClass)// Here getting exception because MyClass instance is null.
{
   var entry = _context.Entry(langTest);
   if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
   {
      myContext.MyClass.Add(entity);
   }
}
```

If any solution or suggestion please put comment, highly appreciated.

Comment: Why does your question have `moq` marked?

Comment: Because i am doing unit testing using Moq. And my test function is working fine, but getting error into the function which i am calling.

Comment: I ask because you don't seem to be constructing `MyContext`, which leads me to believe you might be "mocking" it.

Answer (score 2):

if you used the Database First approach entity framework would generate a DbContext that you can use. check under *.Context.tt you will find your DbContext that you should use. 
And in your DbContext class check if you have your entity in, for example

```
public virtual DbSet<yourEntity> entities { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes, it is virtual i used, 
public virtual DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }